# Get list of simple products which don't belong to a configurable

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product

What is the best way to get a list of simple products which don't belong to a configurable?

I have a shop with mostly simple products which belong to a parent/configurable product. But some of the products (eg. jewellery) don't have options so they've been set up as lone simple products.

**Ps** this is for my own usage only so any solution that provides the right results will do :) thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thomas,Magento did not provide this type on function,So without any coding or MySQL Query,you can not get the solution.

**Mysql:** Magento save the relation between `configurable product and it child products` at `catalog_product_super_link` and save it product basic data  at `catalog_product_entity`  Table.

[image]

Write select query with `select type_id=simple` simple product and check `that product id exit` at `catalog_product_super_link` table  `product_id.` columns.

**For getting Simple products that are not associated with a configurable**

```
    SELECT * FROM `jsw_catalog_product_entity` where entity_id 
not in (SELECT product_id FROM `jsw_catalog_product_super_link`) and type_id='simple'
```

Comment: thanks a lot. You've answered a few of my questions now. I owe you a pint ;)

Comment: Any good idea on how to do something similar in Magento2 using the productRepository?
Can it be done with filters?

Comment: The problem with the query above is that you also select normal simple products.


**Here the one where you only select products that are Not Visible Individually:**  

```SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM catalog_product_super_link) AND type_id='simple' AND entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` WHERE attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'visibility') AND `catalog_product_entity_int`.value = 1);```

Answer (score 2):

Tested in Magento Commerce 2.4.1

This will give you a list of simple products that don't have any parent/child mapping with a configurable product, using a simple left join.

```
select * from catalog_product_entity e
left join catalog_product_super_link sl on sl.product_id = e.row_id
where sl.product_id is null
and e.type_id = 'simple';
```

***Similarly...***

This will give the configurable products with no child assigned.

```
select *, count(sl.parent_id)
from catalog_product_entity e
left join catalog_product_super_link sl on sl.parent_id = e.row_id
where e.type_id = 'configurable'
group by sl.parent_id
having count(sl.parent_id) = 0;
```

**Note:** `catalog_product_super_link`  table keeps the relationship of the parent to child for configurable products and it uses the `row_id` field to map, NOT the `entity_id`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you @Dilhan

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Adobe Commerce `2.4.3-p1`

Created a very simple query to find out the Configurable products Entity Id, SKU, and Type Id for those that have not been associated with any of the Simple Products.

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku, cpe.type_id 
    FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe 
    WHERE cpe.type_id="configurable" AND 
    cpe.row_id NOT IN (
        SELECT parent_id FROM catalog_product_super_link
    )
;
```